# `pandas.pivot_table(aggfunc=np.sum)`を実行したときのFutureWarningの内容について教えてください

Tags: python, pandas

## 環境

- Python 3.11.7
- pandas 2.2.0

## 何が起きたのか

以下のPythonスクリプトを実行したら、`FutureWarning`が発生しました。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["foo", "foo", "bar"],
        "B": [
            "small",
            "large",
            "large",
        ],
        "C": [1, 2, 2],
    }
)

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values="C", index=["A"], columns=["B"], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

```
$ python sample.py
sample.py:16: FutureWarning: The provided callable <function sum at 0x7f772b5b22a0> is currently using DataFrameGroupBy.sum. In a future version of pandas, the provided callable will be used directly. To keep current behavior pass the string "sum" instead.
  table = pd.pivot_table(df, values="C", index=["A"], columns=["B"], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

## 質問

上記の警告の意味について教えていただきたいです。

以下のような認識であっているでしょうか？

- `numpy.sum`を渡しているが、実際には`DataFrameGroupBy.sum`で計算される。
- 将来のpandasのバージョンでは、`numpy.sum`を渡したら`numpy.sum`で計算される。
- `DataFrameGroupBy.sum`で計算したときと同じ挙動にするには、`aggfunc="sum"`を指定すればよい

もし上記の認識が正しい場合、`numpy.sum`を渡してるのに実際には`DataFrameGroupBy.sum`で計算されるのは、なぜでしょうか？

## 参考

pandas 2.0.3ではこの警告が発生しませんでした。
pandas 2.1.0以降で、この警告が発生しました。

Comment: [What's new in 2.1.0 (Aug 30, 2023) — pandas 2.2.0 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.1.0.html) の、"Deprecated replacing builtin and NumPy functions in `.agg`, `.apply`, and `.transform`; use the corresponding string alias (e.g. "sum" for `sum` or `np.sum`) instead (GH 53425)" が該当するのでしょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

metropolis さんのコメントで、自己解決できました。

> numpy.sumを渡しているが、実際にはDataFrameGroupBy.sumで計算される。

yes.警告メッセージ「The provided callable <function sum at 0x7f772b5b22a0> is currently using DataFrameGroupBy.sum」の通り。

> 将来のpandasのバージョンでは、numpy.sumを渡したらnumpy.sumで計算される。

以下のようにpandasコアメンバーが言っているので、たぶんyes。

> I think we shouldn't alias a potentially valid UDF to the pandas version; this prevents users from using the NumPy version of the method if that is indeed what they want.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53425#issue-1729544570

> DataFrameGroupBy.sumで計算したときと同じ挙動にするには、aggfunc="sum"を指定すればよい

yes.警告メッセージ「To keep current behavior pass the string "sum" instead.」の通り。

> もし上記の認識が正しい場合、numpy.sumを渡してるのに実際にはDataFrameGroupBy.sumで計算されるのは、なぜでしょうか？

パフォーマンス向上のためらしいです。

> I think I can remember that this may have been done for performance reasons, i.e. the builtin methods are faster.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53425#issuecomment-1572876694

## 補足

今のpandasだと、どのようなときに問題が起きるかを確認しました。

たとえば標準偏差を算出する`std()`のddof引数のデフォルト値は、numpyでは0、pnadasでは1です。

```
# ddof=0がデフォルト
In [47]: np.std([1,3])
Out[47]: 1.0

In [48]: np.std([1,3], ddof=1)
Out[48]: 1.4142135623730951
```

`agg()`に`np.std`を渡すとpandasの`DataFrameGroupBy.std`計算されます。
したがって、`ddof=0`での計算結果を期待しているのに、実際は`ddof=1`で計算されます。

```
In [49]: df=pd.DataFrame({"a":0,"b":[1,3]})

In [51]: df.groupby("a").agg(np.std)
<ipython-input-51-d7db783eab94>:1: FutureWarning: The provided callable <function std at 0x7f760a038220> is currently using DataFrameGroupBy.std. In a future version of pandas, the provided callable will be used directly. To keep current behavior pass the string "std" instead.
  df.groupby("a").agg(np.std)
Out[51]:
          b
a
0  1.414214
```

しかし、`agg()`に`axis=0`を指定すると、`np.std`が使われるので、`ddof=0`で計算されます。

```
In [52]: df.groupby("a").agg(np.std, axis=0)
Out[52]:
     b
a
0  1.0
```

このように期待と異なる結果になってしまうので、`agg()`に渡す関数は`np.std`でなく`"std"`を渡した方がよい、という警告が出るようです。